# I'm testing a WCF Service and an EF Data layer, receiving String columns as (null), but receive integers as real data. Why are the strings null?

Tags: wcf, ado.net-entity-data-model

```
I'm building a multi-layered Windows VS C# solution that has a WCF Service Library project with EF6.2 loaded, and an ADO.NET Data layer with EF6.2 also.
```

The EDMX model is built as a 'database first' set of tables from my MSSQL Server Express 2016 server on my laptop. My WCF Service Interface and code
only have properties and methods for one of the tables at this point.  And that table has also been built out in logic and data layer methods.
  So, I'm testing that service now with the WCF Test Client, and I'm receiving some integer data correctly in my service's response from to the data layer, but no string data.

```
While testing my "GetMemberByID" method, it returns all String column results as a value of "(null)", and a type of "NullObject",
```

but returns Integers with their actual value.  The WCF Soap response shows the returned String values as "".  But,
 the integers are returned like this:   "7".  There are over 50 data rows in my test database which is used as the source
 for the EF6.2 EDMX build.  My App.config's in data and service layers are referencing the same (localdb)\ V13.0 server and database.

Has anyone had this issue, and can you  tell me what I'm missing?   The MSSQL database was originally an (OleDb) MS Access database and I imported it into
MSSQL Server.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found my mistake.  When translating the business domain objects back to the Service objects in the Service.cs code file, I was only translating the MemberID and the RowVersion - and no other columns.   So, the only thing that was showing up in the WCF Test Client result was the MemberID and the RowVersion - which happen to be the only two non-strings in my entity. All the string types were null because I was not translating them back into the Service.  Thanks for taking a look at this, Abraham, but you made me start looking closer, and thanks for the advice. The MS Documentation was helpful, too. Once I did a full "step into" debug trace from the UI through to the Data Layer and back, I was able to see the data translation failure.   One more thing, before I could debug step by step all the way to the Data layer and back to the Service layer, I had to fix my "Underlying database did not open" issue that so many have had.  I'm hosting my service through my local IIS, and had to make a few changes to the IIS application concerning the user credentials.  My App.config is set to use "Integrated Security=True" - which is a "passthrough" credential in the IIS App pools.  I had my IIS App set to "Specific User", but was not using a UserID/Password in my Connection String.  Once I changed my IIS App to "Passthrough" - I was able to connect, and to debug to the DAL and back.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is something wrong with the serialization process. On my side, the string field can be returned properly. By default, the `DataContractSerializer` is used to deserialize/deserialize the complex object data.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-data-contracts
The most possible reason might be that the nullable field is not decorated by the `[DataMember]` attribute.  Please check if the column of the `DataContract` autogenerated on the client-side contains the `[DataMember]` attribute.
http://sivakrishnakuchi.blogspot.com/2010/05/troubleshoot-wcf-service-returning.html
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: Thanks Abraham.   Here is what the DataContract looks like, I do have "DataMember" attribute for all the properties:     [DataContract]
    public class Member
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int MemberID { get; set; }
        [DataMember ]
        public string Last_Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string First_Name { get; set; }

Comment: 2. Is the DataContract automatically generate by the EDMX, namely the entity class? On my side, here is the default entity class and it works correctly.
    public partial class Book
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Price { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedTime { get; set; }
    }
This entity class definition should correspond to the database table structure.

Comment: Hi Abraham,  Not sure that I  understand what your asking, but I created my own ServiceContract from the default when I created the Service Project, and built my own DataContracts in the Service project.  The EDMX did build the context and .cs files automatically, which I used as the "model" to build my ServiceContract.

Comment: Also, there are only two columns that are not string types - one is the identity and the other is byte[].  The string type is the default and I haven't seen any examples of a string type needing the "Nullable" qualifier in a DataContract.

Comment: Here is the beginning of the auto-generated *.cs file in the EDMX *.tt entry for my table:      public partial class Member
    {
        public int MemberID { get; set; }
        public string Last_Name { get; set; }
        public string First_Name { get; set; }
        public string MidInit { get; set; }
        public string Email_Address { get; set; }
        public string Home_Phone { get; set; }
        public string Cell_Phone { get; set; }
        public string Mailing_Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }

Comment: And here is the ServiceContract's DataContract for that table:      [DataContract]
    public class Member
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int MemberID { get; set; }
        [DataMember ]
        public string Last_Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string First_Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string MidInit { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Email_Address { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Home_Phone { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
         etc